# Is it guaranteed that `Math.cos(0) === [Math.cos][0](0)`?

Tags: javascript, this

In Javascript it's different to use `a.b(c)` or `[a.b][0](c)` the reason being the binding of `this` to the object `a` or not during the execution of the code of `a.b`.

Following the same reasoning using

```
var z = Math.cos;
console.log(z(1));
```

could in theory be different from `console.log(Math.cos(1))` but doesn't seems so in practice.

The question is: is it guaranteed by the standard that for predefined objects like `Math`, `Symbol` or `Object` the `this` context is irrelevant in a compliant implementation?

With `Math` the question seems silly, as apparently there's no reason to depend on the context... however for example for `Symbol.for` it's reasonable to assume that an implementation could store the global symbol table in an object member and in that case using `[Symbol.for][0]("x")` wouldn't work.

`Symbol.for` indeed seems to work fine without context in node, chrome and firefox, but I wonder if this is guaranteed or just incidental...

Comment: Your question seems to assume that for the `Math` library the `this` context has influence on the outcome, I am not exactly sure why the Math library would do anything with the `this` context. So why would this be of any consequence to you?

Comment: @Icepickle What kind of question is that?

Comment: How would the`this` binding affect the return value of a js built-in math function?

Comment: @Icepickle: actually my doubt was about storing `Symbol.for` away in a variable and it seems to work without the need of an explicit bind. I wondered if this is an accident or guaranteed... it's not absurd that a Symbol.for implementation could store the global symbol table in a member of the Symbol object...

Comment: @melpomene As much out of curiosity as his question :)

Comment: @6502 Why didn't you ask about your *actual* usecase then, instead of inventing one using `Math.cos`?

Comment: @Icepickle It's conceivable that the code internal to `Math.cos()` might use `this.PI` instead of `Math.PI`. If you called it with the wrong context, that would fail.

Comment: The `Symbol.for` member table is *global*, meaning there are no other instances it could possibly use.

Comment: @Barmar, true, the question just triggered a why question for me :) But to be honest, if that would be the case, I would expect tons of questions here why `Math.cos` fails, which doesn't seem to be the case :)

Comment: @Barmar even if the approximation used pi I don't see why the lower level language driving a particular js implementation (probably c), and so actually doing thr numerical calculation, would care about the value of Math.PI or this.PI

Comment: @chiliNUT If you don't call the function as `Math.cos(...)` then `this == window` so it would try to use `window.PI`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @chiliNUT I'm not saying it does depend on it, I'm saying that if the implementation were written in Javascript it could have been written that way. So it's not nonsensical that the `Math` functions could depend on the context.

Comment: @Barmar understood, I guess I just wouldn't expect a built-in math function to be implemented in us, though I suppose it is not impossible. And the spec does say the result is implementation dependent...

Comment: Only an instance of one of these built in objects would have a this binding worth using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing in the specification of the [Math object](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-math-object) mentions any use of the `this value`.

Since other parts of the specification are clear when a function depends on `this`, I believe this indicates that the context is not relevant to these functions, and you can safely call them without any context.